# Click button and send picture to second activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclick, android-activity

Im very new in Android.
I have a clickable cardsui (with 22 cards) like this [code](https://github.com/Androguide/cardsui-for-android/blob/master/CardsExample/src/com/cardsui/example/MainActivity.java). Each card should open in the second activity(with three tabs), three different pictures. Each tabs gets one of the three pictures. How looks the intent,if i want to achieve this.

```
    private CardUI mCardView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prozent);


    // init CardView
    mCardView = (CardUI) findViewById(R.id.cardsview);
    mCardView.setSwipeable(false);


    // create a stack1"
    CardStack stack1 = new CardStack();
    stack1.setTitle("Title1");
    mCardView.addStack(stack1);
    // add cards to stack
    mCardView
    .addCardToLastStack(new MyPlayCard(
            "Card1",
            "desc",
            "#e00707", "#e00707", false, true));
    mCardView
    .addCardToLastStack(new MyPlayCard(
            "Card2",
            "desc",
            "#e00707", "#e00707", false, true));
    mCardView.refresh();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, that all looks fine. What are you stuck on? Are you trying to navigate to this activity using an intent?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: i have an activity. in this activity i have 22 cards. if i click on one card this send to the second activity three different images.
My question is, if i should make for each card one activity to get the three images OR can i make just one activity, which gets the three pictures.

sry for my english